# Right syntax for nls() function in R

Tags: r, nls

I am fairly new to R and I am trying to fit a curve using the nls function.
I will first generate a curve y using the dgamma function, which I then want to fit using nls.
Here is my toy example.

```
´´´
x <- 1:250
y <- dgamma(x,2,0.02)
df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)

nls(y~ dgamma(x,a,b),data=df,start =  list(a =2,b =0.4))
´´´
```

The error that I am getting is

*Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) :
Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
In addition: Warning message:
In dgamma(x, a, b) : NaNs produced*

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) nls** This is not a syntax error. The algorithm is not converging.  The problems are:

- dgamma is producing large and/or small numbers causing numeric instabilities
- `nls` tends to have problems with zero residual data, i.e. exact fits. if you are using R 4.1, currently the development version of R, then adding the `nls` argument `control = nls.control(scaleOffset = 1)` may help to avoid such problems  ( see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nls.control.html ).  Below we managed to get convergence without `scaleOffset` so it will work on the current version of R.

Use a spline fit to create more points, 1000 say, and then fit log(y) rather than y.  Use the result of that to fit the original equation continuing to use the additional points.

```
x <- 1:250
y <- dgamma(x, 2, 0.02)

xx <- seq(1, 250, length = 1000)
spl <- spline(x, y, xout = xx)

fo.log <- log(y) ~ dgamma(x, a, b, log = TRUE)
fm.log <- nls(fo.log, data = spl, start = list(a = 2, b = 0.4))

fo <- y ~ dgamma(x, a, b)
fm <- nls(fo, spl, start = coef(fm.log))
fm
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ dgamma(x, a, b)
   data: spl
   a    b 
2.00 0.02 
 residual sum-of-squares: 4.399e-19

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.806e-08
```

**2) optim** `optim` often works well on nonlinear least squares problems.  With it we can get a fit directly without the workarounds above.  The warnings that are produced can be ignored as it reached convergence (`convergence = 0` in the output).

```
rss <- function(p, x, y) sum((y - dgamma(x, p[["a"]], p[["b"]]))^2)
optim(c(a = 2, b = 0.4), rss, x = x, y = y)
```

giving:

```
$par
        a         b 
1.9974423 0.0199842 

$value
[1] 5.209388e-09

$counts
function gradient 
      61       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your suggestion. I am using an older R version and will therefore continue with the optim function.

Comment: I think you have misread the answer. Both (1) and (2) should work without the development version of R.